# "As items arrive" option not available when adding Exchange account

Tags: 8.1, email, exchange

I recently reset my WP8.1 Lumia 1020. Previously I had several Google email accounts and one  Exchange email account (for work, who run their own private Exchange server). All of these were set to sync email "as items arrive".

As I am adding all my email accounts back, the Exchange one no longer lists "as items arrive" as an option in the list. It seems crazy the one account that has a problem is part of MS' own ecosystem!

What's gone wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Exchange should certainly support push mails. Have you tried removing and re-adding that account?

Comment: But does your email appear in the app as it arrives, have you tested that out?

Comment: Does the account show as the Exchange logo rather than an envelope when pinned?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, yeah it does.

Comment: That's very odd then (as all that works for me, albeit with *my company*'s Exchange server), so I can only echo Thomas' comment and suggest removing and re-adding the account.